# Why mean life of radioactive element is slightly greater than halflife..?

Tags: radioactivity, half-life

I was reading radioactivity where I find that half life of a radioactive material is less than mean life due the presence of $\log2$ in the numerator:

$$ t_{1/2} = \frac{0.693}{\lambda} $$

But how what does it mean that the mean life is greater than the half life and why it need to be so?

Comment: How strong is your calculus? Are you familiar with $e$, the natural logarithm, and the magic ways they interact with the kinds of integrals that go into computing an average?

Comment: Possible duplicates [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433645/) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/434114/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link between average lifespan and half time in radioactivity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433645/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the mean life of a radioactive substance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/434114/)

Comment: I do not think that the answer has already been given.  They mainly consists of proving that the relationship between half-life and transformation constant without an explanation in words. If anything [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/324084/104696) has within it the explanation.  I would like to be given the opportunity to write a short answer to this question.

Comment: See also [What is the probability distribution for the detection times of radioactive emissions from a radioactive sample?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/632945/247642)

Comment: TLDR: Half of the atoms in a sample will decay in less time than the half-life. The other half will take longer. Half of the other half will take more than twice as long. A few of the other half will take a _lot_ longer. Those outliers—the ones that take a lot longer to decay—raise the mean lifetime.